# How to deploy my web application on GitHub server?

Tags: java, spring

When I was doing my website in HTML it was easy to deploy it at GitHub repository like github.com/mylogin/myrepos/website.html

But now, I've created more sophisticated website using Vaadin Framework, Java, PostgreSQL etc..
My database is already working online, but how to convert my project to some deployable file? I can't launch InteliJ IDE on the GitHub and run it..

Comment: Yes I know, and I also know that you can have a domain for free over there ;)

Comment: yes. for a static html website. not for what you describe.

Comment: okay so why don't you just write do it on heroku? xD

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between running a static web page on Github Pages and a Java app is that you need a server to run the application code - with Github Pages the html/css/js code is being sent to, and interpreted by a browser.

If you're looking for affordable or free solutions:

- [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com) allows you to set up a linux web server for $3,50/month, it's small but great for personal projects - students get $50 credit for signing up to github.com/education
- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) is a nice solution too, easy to set up. It's worth noting that free Heroku apps go to sleep after a period of inactivity ( counted in minutes, not sure how many but <1h ), after which a request needs to wait 10-60 sec before a dyno is available again.
- If you're interested in cloud - try [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com). You get some hours free each month, the apps won't go offline unless you used the free tier. Also, $200 credit for students to use in a single year is more than enough for personal projects!